# How to Auto generate UUID value for non-primary key using JPA

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have Spring boot application where I am using JPA layer to talk to PostgreSQL. I have a non-primary key of type UUID which I want to auto generate on call of save method. I annotated the attribute with @GeneratedValue but the column value is null on insert.

```
@Column(name = "USER_UUID")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private UUID userUuid;
```

Also I have created the column as:

```
ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS user_uuid uuid UNIQUE DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4();
```

How to auto generate the non-primary UUID value in this case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use JPA callbacks.

```
 @PrePersist
    protected void onCreate() {
        setUserUuid(java.util.UUID.randomUUID());
    }
```